# vim mapping question. How can I make a map to :r! <script> execute right away?

Tags: vim, mapping

I have a python script called showdate.py which I want to map to

I do this by:

```
map <F2> :r! showdate.py
```

in my _gvimrc file.

The problem is that I have to press enter when I press F2 to execute
instead of executing immediately. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a newline to the end of the mapping:

```
map <F2> :r! showdate.py<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will work in your case but I remember using '' to simulate a carriage return. So your line will look like:

```
map <F2> :r! showdate.py <CR>
```